# Handling fs (hadoop shell) command errors in PIG script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a PIG script with a couple of statements.

**Sample script:**

```
register x.jar;
fs -rmr <file-path>;
LOAD 'X' AS  (uuid:chararray,value:chararray);
```

I'm invoking the fs shell to be deleting a file on the HDFS:

```
fs -rmr <file-path>
```

This would delete if present else continue.
If the file/directory is not present, the script exits & throws an error saying: `No such file or directory`

I run it using the following command:

```
pig -f filename.pig -param parameter1=value
```

"-f" is stopping it forcefully.

If I avoid "-f", I get the below error:

```
2015-02-02 02:50:15,388 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParameterSubstitutionException: Undefined parameter : parameter1
```

How can I continue irrespective of this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parameter substitution in a pig script you need to escape the parameters in the script correctly by using the $ sign:

```
fs -rmr $parameter1;
```

If you call the script with `-param parameter1=value` this will replace `$parameter1` with `value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide parameter values while executing the pig script , the following is the syntax.

pig --param parameter1=value filename.pig

Try and let me know if you find any issues